# Lucene/Solr Search Document Creation

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, lucene

I am working on building a search functionality on a website using Lucene. I want to understand the following things to have more clarity

1. Whenever a new web page is created, do I have to create an equivalent document in lucene with fields each time ?
2. Any screenshot/image/diagram of how a lucene document looks like?
3. Once the inverted index is made, is it stored in DB or as a json ?
4. Should the auto correcter Dictionary be made manually as per our business keywords ?

Comment: I recommend you find some good tutorials, and take a look at the resources available to you on the Lucene site starting [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_5_2/index.html). For example, this [sample code](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_5_2/demo/overview-summary.html#overview.description) is helpful. Otherwise, your questions are probably too broad for Stack Overflow. Write some code, and if you get stuck, you can ask a specific question.

Comment: Also, you mention [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/resources.html) and [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/getting-started-elasticsearch?elektra=what-is-elasticsearch&storm=hero-banner-cta&rogue=gs-with-elasticsearch-webinar&utm_expid=.RNNOkg73RwqbzwO3IaaFPQ.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.elastic.co%2Fwhat-is%2Felasticsearch) - each has a great set of "getting started" documentation, which is very relevant to many of the concepts behind Lucene.

Answer (score 1):

These are answer to your questions respectively:

1. yes of course; as soon as as you add or create a document(which is a web page here) you should indexed to make it searchable as soon as you wish.
2. Lucene's document is concept in real world. so a single document means a set of field which comprise a document ( for example a web page is a ducument which contains "Title" , "Body" , "Tags" and "Comment"). so for making this document searchable we create a lucene ducument and tell Lucene to index it. If you are familiar with programming, Lucene documnet is a `class` with some field.

[image: Lucene Document declaration in java]

3. yes of course, but not stored in json. there are a set of files which forms index. and as a point of view it is look like json(because it stored on HDD) but is not really json. It is consist of these formats (segments.gen, segments_N,   write.lock, .cfs, .fnm and so in which you can checkout [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/fileformats.html))

[image: Lucene index files]

4. You can add your own dictionary corrector and meanwhile using the default one.

Comment: Thank you for the insights !

I have another question on this

Lucene uses 'inverted index' right ? So it means, instead of page ->word , it indexes as word->page.
1. But in the image you shared above, how is the index inverted?
2. Also, do the actual search keywords be in those documents ?

Comment: Yes it is; Lucene uses inverted index as you said. Lucene uses inverted index logically. But  implement it as a B+ tree (or hashtable) physically. Because the size of terms are enormous it doesn't prepare as a typical table. It implemented as other data structure to increase speed and optimization and enabling wildcard query( and also query correction). I can refer you to index construction chapter of this book: "Introduction to information retrieval by Christopher Manning".